# Notepad++ Custom Language Styling

Tags: notepad++

I am working with a code that uses several five to 10 digit inputs that are pushed together without white space in between.

If there were four entries, all equal to "0", the code would read like this:

```
0.0000.0000.0000.000
```

should be read:

```
0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
```

The entries may also be entered in scientific form so a real input may look like this:

```
0.0001.2e50.0000.4e-3
```

should be read:

```
0.000 1.2e5 0.000 0.4e-3
```

My question is, is there a way to specify open, escape, and close for a user defined language delimiter style or multiple delimiter styles that would make these values easier to separate visually? Very curious as this would lead to far less frustration when trying to debug.

Comment: There is via _Language -> Define Your Language.._, however from my own experience creating language styles on Notepad++, ditch it for [Atom](https://atom.io/), as Notepad++ does not shine when it comes to customizing language styles.  Atom is not only far more configurable, it has an enormous community of developers, unlike Notepad++, and it's cross-platform _(simply copy your `.atom` directory to whatever OS is being utilized)_. It would also be worth searching the thousands of Atom extensions to see if someone has already created a language style for this.